# Problems with alc256

Tags: sound, alsa, asus, headphones, hda-intel

My laptop (Asus e402s) have the following built in devices:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

There is *one* (this is stupid, since anyone knows that thou shalt never connect two output ports, and if the software dictates what it is, you may blow your components...) analog port which is either microphone or headphone. I want to use the jack as an analog output for headphones. How can I fix that? Currently, *I have no sound in the headphones*, but the speakers work.

```
This is the content of /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 is the following:

Codec: Realtek ALC256
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0256
Subsystem Id: 0x10431d5d
Revision Id: 0x100002
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=3, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x57, nsteps=0x57, stepsize=0x02, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x30 0x30]
  Converter: stream=5, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC256 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x57, nsteps=0x57, stepsize=0x02, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x11 0x11]
  Converter: stream=5, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x05 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
Node 0x07 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x97 0x97]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 1
     0x24
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Device: name="ALC256 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x97 0x97]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 1
     0x23
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x97 0x97]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 1
     0x22
Node 0x0a [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0b [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0c [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0d [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0e [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0f [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x10 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x11 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x12 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40040b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x40000000: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
Node 0x13 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40040b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00010014: OUT EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x15 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x16 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x17 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00003724: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00003724: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00003724: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00: VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00013734: IN OUT EAPD Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x90a70130: [Fixed] Mic at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 2
     0x02* 0x03
Node 0x1c [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400400: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x40479b45: [N/A] SPDIF Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x5
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x1f [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x20 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00040: Mono
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=91
Node 0x21 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0001001c: OUT HP EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x04211020: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x03*
Node 0x22 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 5
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d
Node 0x23 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 6
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d 0x12
Node 0x24 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 2
     0x12* 0x13
```

Comment: Doublecheck "Fast Boot" option in BIOS. It must be disabled

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

After stopping `pulseaudio`, i could use the `hdajackretask` tool. Then I needed to unmute the jack in `alsamixer`, with the `M` key.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you a secret: that one analog port is actually both the mic and the headphone jack and not just "either microphone or headphone". It is capable of both: see TRRS vs TRS: https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/

Given that you still need to do some manual configuration if you want to use different mic or headphone than the headset (headphone + mic) plugged into that jack has. Also the TRRS is backward compatible with simple stereo output jack plug by design.